# How can we add autotext (user name, timestamp) to entries in a mutliline text field in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

For multiline text fields in Azure DevOps work items, is it possible to add functionality that inserts the user name and a timestamp? Our old work tracking solution had a button labeled Stamp that performed this function but the lack of it in DevOps is causing some workflow and auditing issues. The information we need is part of the History for each work item, unfortunately it is not queryable data.

Something like this:

**DeveloperLuke @ 12/20/2018 9:01 AM**

Solution XYZ deployed to ABC.Dev01

**InfraLeia @ 12/20/2018 10:35 AM**

Solution XYZ failed to deploy to DEF.QA01 with error "Resource not responding. A34". Currently investigating.

Comment: If you are going to use a text field like history, why don't you just use the discussion field, since it already stamps it with the user and datetime on save?

Comment: @Matt We are actually trying that approach out now but initial feedback was negative and ultimately prompted my question to SO.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do what you want.  You might can browse through the extensions, but I don't think it exists.  If you care about getting history, you can get the details from this [workitem api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get-a-work-items-full-history).